# Python Pandas : Create new rows from values of a List Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe that look like this :

```
              tags   value
[tag1, tag2, tag3]       0
[tag2, tag3]            10
[tag1, tag3]            50
                       ...
```

On this Dataframe, I want to apply a function that, for each tags of each rows, will create a new row with a column 'tag', and a column 'related_tags'. 
Here is an example of what I am expecting :

```
 tag   value    related_tags
tag1       0    [tag2, tag3] 
tag2       0    [tag1, tag3] 
tag3       0    [tag1, tag2] 
tag2      10    [tag3]     
tag3      10    [tag2]    
tag1      50    [tag3]   
tag3      50    [tag1]
```

I am familiar with Spark DataFrames but not with Pandas, is there a simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) might help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) problem firstly , after explode the list columns `tags`, questions is more clear

```
newdf=unnesting(df,['tags']).reset_index()

newdf['related_tags']=newdf['index'].map(df.tags)

newdf['related_tags']=[list(set(y)-{x})for x , y in zip(newdf.tags,newdf.related_tags)]
newdf
Out[48]: 
   index  tags  value  related_tags
0      0  tag1      0  [tag2, tag3]
1      0  tag2      0  [tag3, tag1]
2      0  tag3      0  [tag2, tag1]
3      1  tag2     10        [tag3]
4      1  tag3     10        [tag2]
```

---

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'tags':[['tag1','tag2','tag3'],['tag2','tag3']],'value':[0,10]})
```

---

self-define [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/7964527)

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx=df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({x:np.concatenate(df[x].values)} )for x in explode],axis=1)
    df1.index=idx
    return df1.join(df.drop(explode,1),how='left')
```